# SSRS Getting the most common entries from a dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a query which returns the following dataset:

```
Device | Service
----------------
PC1    | Service1
PC1    | Service2
PC1    | Service3
PC1    | Service4
PC1    | Service5
PC1    | Service6
PC1    | Service7
PC2    | Service1
PC2    | Service2
```

I have a table in my report that groups by device and also displays the service. But I would also like to have a pie chart showing the five most common services.

I could do this fairly easy using a second dataset and stored proc, but I was wondering if there would instead be a way to do it using this same dataset (the data has already been queried and returned, so it seems to me that it would be better performance than running a separate procedure against the server).

Any thoughts on if this would be possible? Or should I just go with the second query/stored procedure?

Comment: Hi, as you probably know it would be easy to add a pie chart showing all of the service counts from your existing dataset. Unfortunately it would be more difficult to filter the top five as `Filtering on aggregate values for a dataset or data region is not supported.` (from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633648.aspx)

Comment: Thanks paul, that link is helpful. Displaying everything is no problem, its just sometimes (most of the time) the chart can contain so many entries its useless. I'll leave this question open though to see if anyone does have any suggestions and use a separate procedure in the meantime.

Comment: had a thought - if you could include `RowNumber() over (order by count(*))` in your SQL query, then you could certainly filter on that in SSRS

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested query.  If the name of the table you are pulling from is called "#MYTABLE" and it has the two columns returned in your example above, then you would use

```
SELECT #MYTABLE.Device, #MYTABLE.Service, NUMBEROFINSTANCES FROM #MYTABLE
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT SERVICE, COUNT(DEVICE) AS NUMBEROFINSTANCES 
        FROM #MYTABLE
        GROUP BY SERVICE) AS ABB1 ON ABB1.SERVICE = #MYTABLE.SERVICE
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to have the count per group and only show the TOP 5. You can use a CTE with `COUNT(*)OVER` and `DENSE_RANK()OVER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Device, Service
   , COUNT(Service) OVER (PARTITION BY Device) AS Count
   , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Device ORDER BY Service) AS Rank
  FROM tdevice
)
SELECT Count, Rank, Device, Service
FROM CTE
WHERE RANK <= 5
```

Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f42a/8/